# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0:

Tags: python, utf-8, python-unicode

I'm new to python.
I created a code to count how many classes were included in the YOLO annotations, and I encountered this error.

[image]

I'm really unfamiliar with this encoding error. `_'
I searched for this very much, but there is no solution for '0xc4'.

First, I add my entire code.

```
mid_num = 4000
total_num = 13485     #총 이미지 개수
dir = '/media/aicar/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/최종_데이터셋_cone/labels/'         #어노테이션이 있는 위치
# dir = '/home/aicar/labelImg-master/data/'

cone = 0
stick = 0
crossline = 0 
stopline = 0
red_light = 0
yellow_light = 0 
green_light = 0
str_and_left = 0
left_turn = 0
drum = 0


for idx in range(1, mid_num+1):

    # filename = dir + str(idx) + '.txt' 
    filename = dir + 'corn_' + str(idx) + '.txt' 

    # f = open(filename, 'r')
    

    col_2=[]

    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            chars=[]
            line=line.split(' ')
            for char in line:
                if char not in ['',' ']:
                    chars.append(char)
            col_2.append(chars[0])

        f.close()    

    # print(col_2)


    
    if '0' in col_2:
        cone = cone +1

    if '1' in col_2:
        stick = stick +1

    if '2' in col_2:
        crossline = crossline +1

    if '3' in col_2:
        stopline = stopline +1

    if '4' in col_2:
        red_light = red_light +1
    
    if '5' in col_2:
        yellow_light = yellow_light +1

    if '6' in col_2:
        green_light = green_light +1

    if '7' in col_2:
        str_and_left = str_and_left +1

    if '8' in col_2:
        left_turn = left_turn +1

    if '9' in col_2:
        drum = drum +1

    

print('cone : ' + str(cone))
print('stick : ' + str(stick))
print('crossline : ' + str(crossline))
print('stopline : ' + str(red_light))
print('red_light : ' + str(red_light))
print('yellow_light : ' + str(yellow_light))
print('green_light : ' + str(green_light))
print('str_and_left : ' + str(str_and_left))
print('left_turn : ' + str(left_turn))
print('drum : ' + str(drum))
```

The total number of tin I have is 13,485, which is shown in 'total_num', line 5.

If I run this code on 13,485 annotations, the UnicodeDecodeError appears, and if I run about 1,000, it works without problems.

The following image is a terminal window when the code is turned on only 1,000 annotations.

[image]

I need the help of the experts.
Thanks.

Comment: That just means that your file is not encoded in UTF-8 (as is assumed by default), but some other encoding like "euc_kr". You have to add the encoding in your `open` call, e.g. `open(filename, encoding="some-encoding")`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thanks for your answer. 
I added `encoding="ASCII"` in `open` call. (I checked how the annotations were encoded with command 'file' and it came out 'ASCII')
But I got this error => _UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)_

Comment: Please check the file content - obviously there is something in there that is not ASCII. Either it is in another encoding, or the file is just corrupt. You can add a counter in your code to check the line number, and add an exception handler where you can log the failing line number, and check it in the file afterwards.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Many thanks but honestly, It's quite hard for me. And I have two more questions.
1 - Why did this code work when I set the number of annotations it handles 1,000?
2 - What does' failing' and 'an exception handler' mean?

Comment: Sorry, can't really say what exactly goes wrong, I haven't worked with YOLO annotations. An excpetion handler is a `try / except` block around your code, look it up in the Python documentation. You can catch the `UnicodeDecodeEror` and add some logging, or use a debugger to check what is going on.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen
Okay. I got some Python documentation for try/except. I'll try it. Have a good day :)